# Transitions time in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-transitions

I have this css codes for my element that works in firefox and chrome :

```
.button {
border : 1px;
background : #fff;
transition : 1s;
}

.button:hover {
border : 2px;
background : #000;
}
```

And i set a "Transition:1s" for this element.

But now this Transition doesn't work in Internet Explorer.

So, what can i do to have a Transition in IE for this element for 1second ?

***And if Transition is unsupported in IE 8-9 , so can we do it with JQUERY ?***

Comment: just IE10 supports Transition: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @CristinaCristea thanks , i have edited my question. can we use JS to do something like that ?

Comment: IE 10+ supports transitions. You could polyfil for obsolete browsers if you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to what you posted, it should be working by default in internet explorer, as the 'transition' properly is used by it. Are you using a lower version of IE? It may be one that doesn't support transitions

If you guys provide a fiddle that would help!

A format I use myself to guarantee cross browser transitions, I use:

```
webkit-transition: ~~;
-moz-transition: ~~;
-o-transition: ~~;
transition: ~~;
```

This usually ensures browser compatibility, I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

what version of IE are you running with? try to check the compatibility here http://caniuse.com/#search=transition .

because your code work http://jsfiddle.net/bFd9A/1/

```
.button {
border : 1px;
background : #fff;
-webkit-transition : 1s;
-moz-transition : 1s;
-o-transition : 1s;
transition : 1s;
}

.button:hover {
border : 2px;
background : #000;
}
```